# How do I create a background task to collect BLE data in the background on an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to create an app that records and displays heart rate from a BLE device. However, iOS terminates my app once it's in the background after a minute or two. I am creating and ending a background task for every measurement so I'm not sure why it's killing the process.

Here is my peripheral function

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                    error: Error?) {
        switch characteristic.uuid {
            case heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID:
            self.bpm = heartRate(from: characteristic)
            let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            registerBackgroundTask()
            onHeartRateReceived(self.bpm)
            endBackgroundTask()
            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timestamp - startTime), y: Double(self.bpm)))
            hr_array.append(Double(self.bpm))
            time_array.append(Double(timestamp))
            self.timeSinceLastNotification += 1

            if (self.bpm > self.warningHR && self.timeSinceLastNotification > self.timeBetweenNotifications) {
                self.sendNotification(timeInterval: 0.01)  //Notification Capability
                self.timeSinceLastNotification = 0
            }

        default:
            print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }
```

This is my first time experimenting with background threads so it's possible I'm calling these functions in the wrong place. It's also possible that my approach is wrong so please let me know if there is an easier/better way to do this.

Here is the entirety of my code if it is of interest:

```
//
//  newFlightViewController.swift
//

import Charts
import CoreBluetooth
import NotificationBannerSwift
import UIKit
import UserNotifications


let heartRateServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x180D")
let heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A37")
let bodySensorLocationCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A38")

class newFlightViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var heartRateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodySensorLocationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!
    
    
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var heartRatePeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var lineChart = LineChartView() // chart
    var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
    var hr_array: [Double] = []
    var time_array: [Double] = []
    var startTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    var warningHR = 80
    var bpm = 0  // Initializing bpm variable as a class variable
    var timeSinceLastNotification = 10000  // We use this to check that we haven't sent a notification recently
    var timeBetweenNotifications = 30
    var timeSinceLastSave = 100
    var timeBetweenSaves = 10
    var items: [Flight]?
    var newFlight: Flight?
    
    
    let userNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
      
      super.viewDidLoad()
//        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
      lineChart.delegate = self  // chart
      self.userNotificationCenter.delegate = self
      self.requestNotificationAuthorization()  // Notification Capability
  //    self.sendNotification(var timeInterval: Double)  //Notification Capability

//       Make the digits monospaces to avoid shifting when the numbers change
        heartRateLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 100.0, weight: .regular)
        self.newFlight = Flight(context: self.context)
        self.newFlight?.flight_id = randomString(length: 64)
        self.newFlight?.date = Date()
        self.newFlight?.instructor = "INSTRUCTOR"
      
    }
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    
    @IBAction func saveData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Saving Data")
        
        
        let saveBanner = StatusBarNotificationBanner(title: "Data Saved", style: .success)
        saveBanner.show()
    }
    
    func fetchFlights() -> [Flight]?{
        do {
            self.items = try context.fetch(Flight.fetchRequest())
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SupplementaryViewController().tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            
        }
        return self.items
    }
    /////////////////////////////////
    var updateTimer: Timer?
    var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid
    func registerBackgroundTask() {
      backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
        self?.endBackgroundTask()
      }
      assert(backgroundTask != .invalid)
    }
    
    func endBackgroundTask() {
      print("Background task ended.")
      UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
      backgroundTask = .invalid
    }
    
    @objc func reinstateBackgroundTask() {
      if updateTimer != nil && backgroundTask == .invalid {
        registerBackgroundTask()
      }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    func onHeartRateReceived(_ heartRate: Int) {
        heartRateLabel.text = String(heartRate)
        print("BPM: \(heartRate)")
        self.sendNotification(timeInterval: 0.01)
        

        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()
        //
        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set)

        set.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        set.drawFilledEnabled = true
        set.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
        set.colors = [UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)]
        set.lineWidth = 2
        set.drawValuesEnabled = false
        chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 40
        chartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 40
        chartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 160
        chartView.rightAxis.axisMaximum = 160


        chartView.data = data
    }
  }
    

  extension newFlightViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
      switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
          print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
          print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
          print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
          print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
          print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
          print("central.state is .poweredOn")
          centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [heartRateServiceCBUUID])
      @unknown default:
          print("Unknown switch case in function centralManagerDidUpdateState")
      }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
      print("\nCentral\n\n")
      print(central)
      print("\n\n")
      
      print("\nHeart Rate Peripheral\n\n")
      print(peripheral)
      print("\n\n")
      heartRatePeripheral = peripheral
      heartRatePeripheral.delegate = self

      centralManager.stopScan()
//      centralManager.connect(heartRatePeripheral)
        centralManager.connect(heartRatePeripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey:true, CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey: true])

      
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
      print("Connected!")
      heartRatePeripheral.discoverServices([heartRateServiceCBUUID])
    }
  }

  extension newFlightViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
      guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }

      for service in services {
        print(service)
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
      }
    }
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
                    error: Error?) {
      guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

      for characteristic in characteristics {
        print(characteristic)
        if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
          print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
          peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        }
        if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
          print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
          peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        }
      }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                    error: Error?) {
        switch characteristic.uuid {
            case heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID:
            self.bpm = heartRate(from: characteristic)
            let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            registerBackgroundTask()
            onHeartRateReceived(self.bpm)
            endBackgroundTask()
            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timestamp - startTime), y: Double(self.bpm)))
            hr_array.append(Double(self.bpm))
            time_array.append(Double(timestamp))
            self.timeSinceLastNotification += 1

            if (self.bpm > self.warningHR && self.timeSinceLastNotification > self.timeBetweenNotifications) {
                self.sendNotification(timeInterval: 0.01)  //Notification Capability
                self.timeSinceLastNotification = 0
            }

        default:
            print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }

    private func bodyLocation(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> String {
      guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
        let byte = characteristicData.first else { return "Error" }

      switch byte {
        case 0: return "Other"
        case 1: return "Chest"
        case 2: return "Wrist"
        case 3: return "Finger"
        case 4: return "Hand"
        case 5: return "Ear Lobe"
        case 6: return "Foot"
        default:
          return "Reserved for future use"
      }
    }
    
    private func heartRate(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Int {
      guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
      let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)

      let firstBitValue = byteArray[0] & 0x01
      if firstBitValue == 0 {
        // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd byte
        return Int(byteArray[1])
      } else {
        // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd and 3rd bytes
        return (Int(byteArray[1]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[2])
      }
    }
    
    func requestNotificationAuthorization() {
      // Authorization options
      let authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.init(arrayLiteral: .alert, .badge, .sound)
      
      self.userNotificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (success, error) in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error: ", error)
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    func sendNotification(timeInterval: Double) {
      let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      
      // Add content to to notificationContent
      notificationContent.title = "High Heart Rate"
      notificationContent.body = "Heart rate has exceeded \(self.warningHR) bpm"
      notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(value: 3)
      
      
      
      // Add an attachment to the notification content
      if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "generic_hr_heart", withExtension: "png") {
        if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "generic_hr_heart", url: url, options: nil) {
            notificationContent.attachments = [attachment]
        }
      }
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "highHR", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
        
        userNotificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Notification Error: ", error)
          }
        }
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      completionHandler()
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        completionHandler([.badge, .sound, .banner])
      } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
      }
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveAndEndFlight(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Ending Flight")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //        performSegue(withIdentifier: "recordFlightStatsSegue", sender: self)
    }
      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
          var vc = segue.destination as! GradeSheetViewController
          
          self.newFlight?.hr_array = self.hr_array
          self.newFlight?.time_array = self.time_array
         
          
          
          do {
              try self.context.save()
          }
          catch {
              print("Error Saving Flight")
          }
          self.fetchFlights()
          
          SupplementaryViewController().fetchFlights()
          
          vc.timeArray = self.time_array
          vc.newFlight = self.newFlight
      }
      
      func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
      }
  }
```

EDIT: Background Modes are enabled
[image: Background Mode Settings in Xcode]

Comment: Are you using any of the [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) available?

Comment: This is almost certainly the issue. If you have a BLE background mode, and are continuously connected to the device, you shouldn't need any background tasks. The app should be awakened any time the characteristic changes if you're subscribed to it. Note that this is not in any way related to "background threads." You should also not call `beginBackgroundTask` or `endBackgroundTask` for any of this.

Comment: Your mistake (among making this too complicated with background tasks) is that you're trying to update a view while in the background. Don't do that. Just update model data. When the app comes into the foreground, then update your view to match your model. There is absolutely no reason to update a view that the user can't see.

Comment: In addition to Rob's comments (which are both correct observations) you should look into [Core Bluetooth state preservation and restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5).  No iOS app lives forever. iOS can relaunch your Bluetooth app if you set it up correctly.  Moving your Core Bluetooth code out of a view controller and into its own object will help you manage this too.

Comment: Your app uses ExternalAccessory and acts as a Bluetooth peripheral? (These are both somewhat rare. Did you really mean to include these?)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the resources posted. I'm new to Swift so they're all valuable. Updated the post to show the background modes. I added the background tasks because iOS kept shutting off my app in the background anyway without them and I thought this may be the solution. Will moving the view updates out of the `onHeartRateReceived` stop iOS from stopping the app?

If my app needs to be relaunched, does that mean that the app stopped collecting data?

Comment: @RobNapier Somewhere along the way I added those to see if they fixed the problem and never removed them.

Comment: There's too much here to debug all of it. Simplify this program (typically by creating a small, stand-alone app that does one thing for testing). Get rid of the UNNotification stuff. Move all the bluetooth work into its own object that isn't tied to the ViewController; the ViewController should just observe the Bluetooth object. Make this as small as possible, and see if it runs when you expect. Make sure you're really getting notifications from the device, and look for logs to tell you what's happening, not UI updates (which are more complex).

Comment: @RobNapier That is extremely helpful thank you! Do you have any resources you recommend for creating objects in one file and observing them in another file?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1000705-model-view-controller-mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach